# Изменение одного элемента в динамическом списке v-for

Tags: vue.js

Всем привет! Решаю следующую задачу: с помощью цикла v-for вывожу динамические данные с сервера в виде списка сотрудников с чекбоксом, у каждого есть ФИО, ID. Мне нужно проставить явку каждому сотруднику. Например, по умолчанию чекбокс checked, и явка проставляется всем автоматом. Но если нужно проставить прогул, я должен убрать галочку с нужного сотрудника и проставить ему "прогул". Как это сделать?

```
    <template>
        <div>
            <ul 
                v-for="(employee, employee.id) in object" 
                :key="employee.id">
            <input 
                type="checkbox" 
                checked>
            <li>{{ employee.name }}</li>
            <span>{{ turnout }}</span>
            </ul>
         </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        export default {
            data() {
                return {
                    object: [],
                    turnout: 'Yes'
                 };
               }
             }
    </script>
```

Comment: Сначала нужно работников `object: []` на работу принять )

Answer (score 0):

Первое - v-for повторяет эллемент на котором используется, мало вероятно что нужно повторять ul, скорее li

Второе, tournout - это свойство объекта должно быть. Иначе у тебя массив сотрудников, но одно свойство tournout привязанное ко всем сотрудникам?

Третье, это свойство объекта привязывается к чекбоксу.

Примерно так:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(employee, employee.id) in object"
          :key="employee.id">
        <label>
          <input
              type="checkbox"
              v-model="employee.turnout"
          >
          {{ employee.name }}
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        object: []
      };
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Я не могу повлиять на данные с сервера, которые мне приходят, там явки нет. Как мне добавить явку в этот массив object: [ ]?

Comment: Добавить можно так например:
````
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        object: []
      };
    },
    mounted() {
      object.forEach(e => e.tournout = true);
    }
  }
</script>
````

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать!

Comment: Но не понятно, как тогда используется этот tournout, если сервер не выдает и видимо не получает данные о прогуле. Этот прогул каким образом должен сохранятся на сервере?

Comment: да, тут следующие задачи: 
1. Нужно визуально показать пользователю, что явка проставлена (либо прогул) - поэтому и в шаблон я завожу
2. Данные о явке (прогуле) должны уходить обратно на сервер

Comment: Изначально правильно делать это на стороне бекенда все же, так как фронт (шаблон) все равно придется менять. Если на сервере сохранен прогул, то во фронте он также должен отобразиться при обновлении страницы. В любом случае, сейчас - это даже не временное решение, а чисто дизайнерское может. Тут нет вопроса яйца и курицы, тут бекенд перворожденец, а фронт - интерфейс для работы с бекендом ) И идти от бекенда нужно )

Comment: Согласен! Бекенд это 1С, там свои ограничения, мне программист с той стороны отдает что может говорит